# Instance Of Selected java file is always returning null -- eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the instance of the Selected java file into eclipse.

When I googled, I got the below code.

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window
                .getSelectionService().getSelection();

        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            IStructuredSelection ssel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
            Object obj = ssel.getFirstElement();
            IFile file = (IFile) Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(obj, IFile.class);
            if (file == null) {
                if (obj instanceof IAdaptable) {
                    file = (IFile) ((IAdaptable) obj).getAdapter(IFile.class);
                }
            }
            if (file != null) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

But this code is always returning null for file. Kindly help.
It has got the correct values till obj. But it cannot make IFile object.

Comment: It'd be better to attach a debugger to it and see what `obj` is first, then see if passing the value in `obj` should return an `IFile` for you.

Comment: the javadoc of getAdapter have the following clause:"Note that this method will never cause plug-ins to be loaded. If the only suitable factory is not yet loaded, this method will return null." - What should be done to load the plugin??

Comment: If you've opened a view provided by JDT, or one of its editors, preference pages, or anything it contributes to the UI, it's already loaded.  As +Makoto said, Debug it. Look and see what's actually going on.

Comment: Where are you running this code? A handler? Some sort of listener? or what?